# Next.js next-auth.js with Azure Active Directory B2C The redirect URI is not registered

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, next-auth

I encountered the "redirect_uri_mismatch" error when using next-auth.js to sign in through Azure AD B2C.
The error description is as follows: "The redirect URI 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/azure-ad-b2c' provided in the request is not registered for the client ID 'c716xxx8406'."

I have configured the project as follows

next-auth route

```
    const handler = NextAuth({
        AzureADB2CProvider({
            tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_TENANT_NAME,
            clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_SECRET!,
            primaryUserFlow: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_PRIMARY_USER_FLOW,
            authorization: { params: { scope: "offline_access openid" } },
        })
    ],
    pages: {
        signIn: '/'
    }
})
export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

signin button components

```
export default function Home() {
  const { data: session } = useSession()

  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <p>
        Signed in as {session?.user?.email ?? ''}
      </p>
      <button onClick={() => signIn('azure-ad-b2c')}>sign az</button>
      <button onClick={() => signOut()}>sign out</button>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Azure App Registration and next.js project directory
[image]

[image]

Error message
[image]

Should I configure anything else?

next.js version: 13.4.1
next-auth.js version: 4.22.1

Comment: where you able to find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem.

Web Redirect URIs for your App Registration in Azure should have both the NextAuth callback URL (`http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/azure-ad-b2c`) as well as the `Callback URL` from the identity provider you're using with your B2C User Flow. You can find this URL in the "configure" panel on the Identity Providers page in your Azure AD B2C tenant. It should look something like:

```
Callback URL
https://TENANT-NAME.b2clogin.com/TENANT-NAME.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp
```

On a related note I see you're using a custom `signIn` page. Using a custom `signIn` page with NextAuth introduces a problem where redirects aren't *always* handled correctly depending on how you invoke the `signIn` function (i.e. `signIn("azure-ad-b2c")`). See my comment in this [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/5409#issuecomment-1560127799) for more details. At the time of writing, this edge-case isn't mentioned anywhere in the NextAuth documentation.

I was *finally* able to get the AzureADB2C NextAuth provider working once I added *both* Redirect URIs to my App Registration, and added some additional code to my project to handle post-authentication OAuth2 redirects (which wasn't working because I was using a custom `signIn` page by setting `AuthOptions.pages.signIn`).

Hope this helps someone, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error but was able to get around it by matching up 'id' value and the endpoint in Redirect URL.

```
AzureADB2CProvider({
  **id: 'azure-ad-b2c',**
  tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_TENANT_NAME,
  clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_ID as string,
  ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/azure-ad-b2c' in the redirect URLs section under Authentication > Platform configurations > **Single-page application**.

then,

```
  pages: {
    signIn: "/",
  }, 
  checks:["pkce"],
  client:{
        token_endpoint_auth_method:"none"
      }
```

should be configured in NextAuthOptions